# Why is my Laravel query returning the the index number and name?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, lumen

This route in Laravel...

```
$app->get('/{username}/firstname', function (Request $request, $username){
   $user = DB::connection('db1')->select('select `firstname` from `iosUsers` where `username` = ?', [$username]);
   var_dump($user);
});
```

is giving me this...

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(7) "Cameron"
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Cameron"
  }
}
```

as opposed to how it's expected to return with just the key name, not the number as well.
I have no idea why It's displaying it twice with both index types. I want it to be just the name.

The problem started when I switched to database.php instead of using the *.env* file.

Comment: Try by removing `::connection('db1')`. Also try another way of selecting: `DB::table('iosUsers')->select('firstname')->where('username', $username)->get()`. Check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) for more different ways to use queries in Laravel. Also you may consider using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent) since it is very easy to use and adds more functionality.

Comment: Still giving me the same result.

Comment: Think you have this informations twice in your db

Answer (score 1):

Try to instead use `DB::table` and make sure to `->get()` the query so you run it.

**Change**

```
$app->get('/{username}/firstname', function (Request $request, $username){
   $user = DB::connection('db1')->select('select `firstname` from `iosUsers` where `username` = ?', [$username]);
   var_dump($user);
});
```

**To**

```
$app->get('/{username}/firstname', function (Request $request, $username){
    $user = DB::table('db1')->selectRaw("select `firstname` from `iosUsers` where `username` = ?", [$username]);
    var_dump($user);
});
```